# Can you add CSS for desktop only that is resolution independent?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Can you detect if the user is viewing your website from a touch enabled device, or is using a mouse?

There are very large tablets and tiny laptops, so I feel like media queries based on screen size don't do the trick.

For context: I have some buttons with an extra element. I want that element to be displayed by default when viewing from phone or tablet, and to be displayed on hover when viewing from laptop/desktop.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible to detect if the website is viewing through touch enabled system. media query `hover` and `pointer` can be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a more reliable way, you can use the `pointer` and `hover` media queries separately or together to achieve what you are tryig.

```
/* smartphones, touchscreens */
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
    /* ... */
}
/* stylus-based screens */
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: fine) {
    /* ... */
}
/* Nintendo Wii controller, Microsoft Kinect */
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: coarse) {
    /* ... */
}
/* mouse, touch pad */
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    /* ... */
}
```

`Pointer` media query helps you to understand the kind of pointing device with which the site is being used. Values to the `pointer` media query are 'fine', 'coarse', and 'none'.

While `hover` media query is used to understand if the primary interactive mechanism can hover over elements with ease. The values are 'hover' and 'none'.